# Intermittent java.net.SocketPermission" "server.domain.com:1433" errors?

Tags: java, sql-server

I've been seeing an odd problem with a JNLP Java desktop application which uses several databases (all on the same server).  It'll throw these java.net.SocketPermission" "server.domain.com:1433" errors while opening a database connection (Microsoft SQL Server), but only very rarely, and only in one particular section of code and connecting to one particular database (and I do mean "database", not a specific "table").  Never has this happened with connections to any of the other databases residing on that server (It has around 2 dozen databases with thousands of tables).

I've never actually been able to catch it on my development machine, but we have a user (not specific user, it varies) hit it once about every 3-4 weeks.

I'm really not sure what to look for on this.  I've already confirmed permissions and code to the best of my ability.  Is there another class of issue I should look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a database connection is started in a method that is invoked as the result of a javascript action, it will force a security prompt.  Then, if the user "cancels" the prompt, the connection will be denied, resulting in this error.

The solution was to force the initial database connection to come up at the start of the core Java application and not "as needed" since sometimes the first need was the result of a javascript action...  This not only avoids the possibility of the error, but also removes an annoying security prompt from the life of the users.